# How can i split my agents in AnyLogic so that one always goes to a service then the rest goes to another service?

Tags: split, process, modeling, agent, anylogic

I'll explain my problem.
I'm adding two pictures of part of my scenario.[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOmi9.png)[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMTD6.png)

I would like to know how to split my agent Groups composed of 1 or 5 agents so that a member of the group always goes to the ticket office while the other members of the group go to the service.
For example I would like a group of 3 to go 1 in the ticket office and the other 2 go to the service and queue there.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: have you tried the ped group disassemble block? Assuming that you are using the pedestrian library

Comment: In my class we used only the Process modeling library and the task was supposed to be answered using this library. :/

Comment: how did you create groups then? You need to add the images you promised.. there are no images in your post...

Comment: here they are! Sorry the link wasn't working before! The first one is an insight on how the source block is setted. The second one is ssimply the situation of the source and the 2 service blocks.

Answer (score 1):

So this is what I would do:

First, your group agent, create a variable called groupId defined as an int.

Second, in main create this structure:
[image: structure]
groupSize is an int
currentGroupId is an int with initial value equal to 1
getGroupSize function has the following code:

```
groupSize=uniform_discr(1, 5);
return groupSize;
```

In your source in agents per arrival:

```
getGroupSize()
```

In your source in the on at exit action:

```
agent.groupId=currentGroupId;
currentGroupId++;
```

And finally in the selectOutput you use if condition is true with the following condition:

```
agent.groupId==1
```

And the following code in the on enter action:

```
if(groupSize==agent.groupId)
    currentGroupId=1;
```